# Active directory C# connection check and get User detail

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, ldap, ldapconnection

In Active directory, I am trying to connect to `LDAP` server and trying to check if `user` us valid or not. But the below code throws the exception error.
I am not sure where i am going wrong.. Even whether the connection made is correct or not. I tried the same connection name and password into the `Apache directory studio` which i am able to connect successfully but not through the code.It throws the exception from `myLdapConnection` please can you check where i am going wrong. My connection which i am using in the `Apache directory studio` is secure connection .. Do i need to specify the `LDAPS` or ldap will work

```
public void GetAllADUsers( string username)
{
    try
    {

        DirectoryEntry myLdapConnection = new DirectoryEntry();
myLdapConnection.Path = "LDAP://server:port/o=value";
myLdapConnection.Username = @"CN=cn,OU=ou,OU=Users,O=o";
myLdapConnection.Password = "password";

//myLdapConnection.AuthenticationType = AuthenticationTypes.Secure;

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(myLdapConnection) { Filter = ( "(&(objectClass=user)") };

     SearchResultCollection allResults = search.FindAll();
        if(allResults.Count == 0)
{

            Console.WriteLine("not found");
 }
else
{
Console.WriteLine ("found");
}
catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
 }
```

**Note** username if i specify `= @"CN=cn,OU=ou,OU=Users,O=o";` myLdapConnection threw the DirectorySearcherCOMException but if only pass the username =**cn** means on cn value.. this gives all the values

*exception*

at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)\r\n   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()\r\n   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()\r\n   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)\r\n   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll()\r\n   at _Default.GetAllADUsers(String username)

Comment: can you try the username as `joe.bloggs@company.com`?

Also, what is the exception (apart from ComException)?

Also, `(&(objectClass=user)` is incorrect LDAP syntax, try `(objectClass=user)`.

Comment: @zaitsman done the same but same except which is /o=textron.com `Stepping over non-user code 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll'
The thread '<No Name>' (0x22a0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x20ac) has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Comment: what you posted is NOT an exception. Also, what username did you specify?

Comment: @zaitsman please check the post above ... I have edited the exception and username  if trying with above and only `cn` value both are not working

Comment: you posted PART of your stack trace; as for the CN, can you please try with user@company.com WITHOUT ANY CN